# Mercurial post update hook

Tags: mercurial, hook, mercurial-hook

Is there a way to run a hook after an update command (e.g. `hg up -r tagName`).

I don't really have much experience in hooks and it seems most guides are based on post commits, pulls or pushes. In a team we commit and push regularly, but only update those instances when ready with a new revision. So we only want to run some code when that state of working directory is needed. Not every commit or push.

Capisce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This book chapter](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) mentions that there is an `update` hook, which should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Perfect. I Couldn't seem to find any mention of it. Thanks